# VBA dictionary not assigning value to key

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, spreadsheet

I created a function getField that looks through the second column and third column of a spreadsheet and returns a dictionary with the keys being the second column and the values being the third. The function takes in a string that is the field name that is being looked for but right now I can't assign a value to the key. Here's the line I'm referring to which currently works but the value is empty my attempt to assign the value failed so I put it in a comment to show you all what I tried. `If InStr(data(r, 1), fieldName) > 0 Then dict(data(r, 1)) = Empty 'dict(value(r, 1))`

Here's the rest of the code:

```
Public Function getField(fieldName As String)

    Dim data(), dict As Object, r As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns(2).value
    value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns(3).value

    For r = 1 To UBound(data)

        If InStr(data(r, 1), fieldName) > 0 Then dict(data(r, 1)) = Empty 'dict(value(r, 1))
     Next

    data = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys())

    Set getField = dict

End Function
```

Comment: `dict(data(r, 1)) = value(r, 1)`  You've not defined `value` so might want to add that.

Comment: If you are trying to create a dictionary where the keys come from the Data array and the values from the Value array then you need to change dict(data(r,1))=dict(value(r,1)) to dict(data(r,1))=value(r,1). In your erroring code dict(value(r,1)) is reading a value from dict using the key value(r,1) which probably doesn't exist, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

The code as presented shows that you are not helping yourself.

There is an undeclared variable Value.
There is no return type declared for the function.

So please insert Option explicit at the start of each Module and then install the fantastic RubberDuck add in and take a look at the code inspections.  These two actions will remove a lot of pain for your life when writing VBA macros.

As I mentioned in my comment the reason the code is not working is because of this construct.

```
dict(data(r, 1)) = dict(value(r, 1))
```

where dict(value(r,1)) is being used with value(r,1) as the key for the dictionary value.  This means that the first time this construct is used it will fail because there is not data in the dictionary and therefore dict(value(r,1)) is trying to access non existent data.

The correct structure is

```
dict(data(r,1) = value(r,1)
```

where the value to be put into the dictionary at dict(data(r,1)) is the value stored in the variant array value at Index (r,1).

For a scripting.dictionary there are two ways in which to add data

```
Dict.add Key, Value
```

and

```
Dict(Key)=Value
```

The first of the above will fail if the key is already present in the dictionary.
The second method is a double edged sword as it will created an entry for the key if the key is not present in the dictionary and then assign value.  HOWEVER, if the key already exists it will overwrite any existing value assigned to the key.  This may or may not be the behaviour that is required.

For the add method we can avoid an error occurring for duplicate keys by testing for the presence of the key in the dictionary using the 'exists' method.

```
If not dict.exists(key) then
    dict.add key,value
Else
    ' what ever action is needed in the case of duplicate keys
End if
```

The code presented by the OP is updated and presented below.

```
Public Function getField(fieldName As String) as Scripting.Dictioanry

    Dim myKeys As Variant   'Formerly data
    myKeys = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns(2).Value)

    Dim myItems As Variant  'Formerly value but not declared
    myItems = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns(3).Value)

    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim myDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For myRow = 0 To UBound(myKeys)

        If Not dict.Exists(myKeys(myRow)) Then

            dict.Add myKeys(myRow), myItems(myRow)

        Else

            Debug.Print "Duplicate Key found: ", myKeys(myRow)

        End If

     Next

    ' No longer required
    ' data = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys())

    Set getField = dict

End Function
```

If we had the situation where we wanted to capture all values even when the key is duplicated then we would simply create a dictionary of dictionaries

```
Public Function getField(fieldName As String) As Scripting.Dictioanry

    Dim myKeys As Variant   'Formerly data
    myKeys = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns(2).Value)

    Dim myItems As Variant  'Formerly value but not declared
    myItems = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns(3).Value)

    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim myDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For myRow = 0 To UBound(myKeys)

        If Not dict.Exists(myKeys(myRow)) Then

            ' add a new dictionary as the value for the key
            dict.Add myKeys(myRow), New Scripting.Dictionary

        End If

        ' now add the value to the dictionary seleted by the key
        ' we just use the current size of the sub dictionary as the index (key)
        ' for the value
        With dict.Item(myKeys(myRow))

            .Add .Count, myItem(myRow)

        End With

     Next

    Set getField = myDict

End Function
```

The above code creates a dictionary where the value assigned to each key is itself a dictionary.  The sub dictionary collects all values that have the same key.  You could of course use a collection rather than a sub dictionary as this removes the need to manage the key for the sub dictionary.

To retrieve information from the dictionary of dictionaries you have to remember that the key retrieves a dictionary

```
myValue = dict.item(key).item(index)
```

Where Item is the default member used for accessing dictionary values (which is usually hidden) e.g. The above could be written, less  intuitively as

```
myValue = myDict(key)(index)
```